# ld: library 'nsl' not found, /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1 in macOS

Tags: macos, go, compiler-errors, clang, macos-sonoma

I downloaded a program written in go and wanted to compile it on my Macbook M1 macOS Sonoma 14.2.1. I have tried several commands and some of the errors are:

`go build -buildvcs=false` 
`env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=arm64 go build`
and this error gives me:

/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
ld: library 'nsl' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

`CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -buildvcs=false`
and this error gives me:

github...: build constraints exclude all Go files in /Users/...

I am a beginner in Go and also in Mac. I have been able to compile this program on Linux but not on my laptop, which is a Mac. Please help

I have tried with
`go clean -modcache go mod tidy`
among others, I have seen that other users on Mac have been able to solve this type of messages

Comment: What is the library? It requires cgo and is trying to link to libnsl, so it’s obviously not all written in Go.

Comment: a tool for the analysis of MD trajectories https://github.com/rmera/gomd